# How to execute the js file once the react component is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 4 react components header,modal,container,index. In index.js I'm rendering all the components. Now, I have one problem My HTMl page is using one js file(home.js). It is executing the before the DOM loads. So, it is not getting any properties of the DOM so it is failing. So, How I can the execute that js file once the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Do you use some module bundler? Webpack or Browserify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `home.js` code with a global function and call to that function in `componentDidMount` life cycle method of your root React component.

So your `home.js` file will look something like this.

```
window.executeHome = function() {
  // your curren home.js code goes here
}
```

and inside the `componentDidMount` method of your root React component, you can call above method to make sure that you are running `home.js` code after loading the React components.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.executeHome();
}
```

However, consider this as a workaround and it's usually not something recommended. The better approach would be writing your `home.js` code also inside a React component.

Comment: `windows` ? when did they rename the global object :D

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine. But, I made some changes if I  declare a function with window.executeHome() it is showing an error. So, I made like executeHome() as normal function and inside that, I have my home.js code and in ``componentDidMount()`` I'm just calling that function with ``this``.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
componentDidMount() {
   
}
```

**componentDidMount()**  automatically called after render() method.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to automatically create a  tag in html file once the component is rendered.

Class-based component:

```
componentDidMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "/path/to/resource.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

If you are a fan of Hooks in React, then useEffect is a great way to append external JS files.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "/path/to/resource.js";
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script);
  }
}, []);
```

You can have a look at this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668) for more information